# Position Eigenstates of Harmonic Oscillator Using Squeeze States

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Ultimately, I want to establish a relationship between an eigenstate of position and an energy eigenstate of a harmonic oscilator.

If we take the squeezing operator and let $ \gamma \rightarrow \infty$, the uncertainty in $x$ will become zero. Hence, people say that $S_{\infty} | 0 \rangle = e^{-\frac{1}{2}a^ta^t} | 0 \rangle$ is a position eigenstate. If I apply $x \sim (a + a^t)$, I get zero which shows that it is the eigenstate for a particle position at zero. Question is, if this is a position eigenstate which is so claimed, how exactly do I go about generating any arbitrary position state $|x \rangle$?

I know that the translation operator can get to a coherent state. Letting $y = x\sqrt{2m\omega}$ the coherent state is
$$ | y \rangle = e^{-y^2/2}e^{ya^t} | 0 \rangle$$
$$ S(\gamma \rightarrow \infty) | y \rangle = e^{-1/2 a^t a^t} e^{-y^2/2} e^{ya^t} | 0 \rangle $$

Since $[a^ta^t, a^t] = 0$ the eigenstate becomes $|y \rangle = e^{-y^2/2} e^{ya^t-\frac{1}{2}a^ta^t} | 0 \rangle$. Does this make sense, is it correct? So conceptually, I translate the energy state of the harmonic oscillator and then squeeze it until the uncertainty in $x$, goes to zero...

Comment: I think that "eigenstate of position operator" is what you mean. Not position eigenstate of the harmonic oscillator? If so, then, yes, it works.

Comment: right, with the eigenstate of the position operator written in terms of the energy eigenstate of the harmonic oscillator?

Comment: What is wrong with just writing $|x\rangle = \sum_n |n\rangle \langle n| x\rangle$. Seems an easier way.

Comment: I want to know what $\langle n | x \rangle$... with this formula I can use the fefinition of $|n \rangle$ in terms of $a, a^t$ to figure it out.

Comment: $\langle n|x\rangle =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n n! \sqrt{\pi}}} H_n(x) e^{-x^2/2}$ is the oscillator wavefunction.

Comment: I am working my way to that result I guess ... I was not aware.